# Tracking amount of time spent on a particular website : Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Requirement:** Make a **chrome extension** that tracks the amount of time a person spends on a profile pages. (Let's say: Facebook's profile page.)

Files: `background.js` (Here we will attach listeners and set intervals.

This is what I have in place for now: (Assume relevant constants)

```
const urlRegex = new RegExp(/.+/); // pass everything for now

function updateActiveTabState() {
    // If idle, ignore
    chrome.idle.queryState(IDLE_TIME, state => {
        // User is active
        if (state === "active") {
            chrome.tabs.query({
                    active: true,
                    lastFocusedWindow: true
                },
                tabs => {
                    if (tabs.length === 0) return;

                    const tab = tabs[0];
                    const tabID = tab && tab.id;
                    const tabURL = tab && tab.url;

                    if (
                        tab &&
                        tabURL && ["loading", "complete"].indexOf(tab.status) > -1
                    ) {
                        if (!urlRegex.exec(tabURL)) return;

                        const uniqueDomain = tabURL && getUniqueId(tabURL);

                        if (!uniqueDomain) return;

                        chrome.windows.get(tabs[0].windowId, function (currentWindow) {
                            if (currentWindow.focused == true) {
                                updateLocal(uniqueDomain, tabID);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
}

function updateLocal(domain, tabId) {
    const apps = JSON.parse(localStorage["apps"]);

    if (!apps[domain]) {
        tabIdDomains[tabId] = domain;
        apps[domain] = {
            sumTime: UPDATE_INTERVAL
        };
    } else {
        apps[domain].sumTime += UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    }

    localStorage["apps"] = JSON.stringify(apps);
}

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(onTabClosed);

setInterval(function () {
    updateActiveTabState();
}, UPDATE_INTERVAL * 1000);
```

Problem: Is this the right way to track this? Note that I need to push the data about a particular URL. That is the reason I have added a listener to the **TabClose** event. Please let me know if I should post that method as well.

In production, there are no errors but the time captured by this script is in minutes (4, 5 or 7) at max. What could be the reason behind it? Does the background script become inactive after some time and hence my extension is unable to track the usage?

Comment: AFAICT this API detects system idle state, which is not directly related to user actions inside the page. The usual approach is to run a content script that listens to various mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: May be you're right. And if you are, shouldn't my script record more time than the actual? That's the problem. It records a max of 7 minutes. I am trying to find out why.

Comment: It still fits: the user switches to another app so the system is not idle, but Chrome is.

Comment: I am also querying for the active tab which will be null so I already take care of that.

Comment: It won't be null: tabbed windows in Chrome always have exactly one active tab.

Comment: Okay, cool. But not really solving the problem.

Comment: That's exactly my point - chrome.idle won't help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185746/discussion-between-abhishek-soni-and-woxxom).